# UIButton ImageView Taking More Space in iCarousel and not Responding to touch Event

Tags: ios5, uiimageview, uibutton, icarousel

I am beginner trying to make a menu using **iCarousel**. What I have tried so far is return a UIButton with a custom image for each view in carousel. The image list has been declared same as told in examples. Problems I am facing are:

1. button (view returned in carousel) - its image is not adjusting properly as shown in fig.
2. Also you can see that when I am displaying bear, it is picking description of Tiger!
3. When I tap any pic, it just scroll forward instead of reacting to button touch down event.

[image]

```cs
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

    //set up carousel data
    wrap = YES;

    self.menuItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bear.png",
                    @"Zebra.png",
                    @"Tiger.png",
                    @"Goat.png",
                    @"Birds.png",
                    @"Giraffe.png",
                    nil];

    self.descriptions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bears Eat: Honey",
                         @"Zebras Eat: Grass",
                         @"Tigers Eat: Meat",
                         @"Goats Eat: Weeds",
                         @"Birds Eat: Seeds",
                         @"Giraffes Eat: Trees",
                         nil];
}

return self;
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSInteger index = [aCarousel indexOfItemViewOrSubview:sender];

switch (index) {
    case 0:
    NSLog(@"at index: %d",index);
        break;

    case 1:
    NSLog(@"at index: %d",index);
      break;   

    case 2:
        NSLog(@"at index: %d",index);
        break;  
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"at index: %d",index);
        break;  
    case 4:
        NSLog(@"at index: %d",index);
        break; 
    case 5:
        NSLog(@"at index: %d",index);
        break;  
    }  }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
aCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeInvertedRotary;
aCarousel.delegate = self;
aCarousel.dataSource = self;
//aCarousel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 68, 320, 257);

[super viewDidLoad];
}


#pragma - mark iCarousel Delegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel 
{
    return [self.menuItems count];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    // limit the number of item views loaded concurrently (for performance)
    return 4;
}

- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240.0f, 200.0f);

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[menuItems objectAtIndex:index]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
    //button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;  

     return button;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    // usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return 240; //for 220 px image
}

- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return self.wrap;
}

- (void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [descriptions objectAtIndex:carousel.currentItemIndex]]];
}
```

I am really fed up trying adjusting carousel for hours. Although I tried aspectfitratio, adjusting frame but don't know why output is wrong. Can please someone figure out where am I doing wrong? Thanks alot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I was able to solve issue by myself. Don't know why my project was behaving so odd, so I decided to use iCarousel in new Project. The mistakes I noted were as follows:

1. In nib file, when I was making class type to iCarousel for subview, it was showing something like **"I Carousel"** in *objects list* - I changed the name in the list manually to my *IBOutlet iCarousel object* as "aCarousel".
2. Secondly I wasn't properly assigning UIButton to UIView in `-(UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` method. I am glad that I found **"Button demo"** in Examples folder. From there I copied my code and now everything is working awesome! :)

Copying Code here for anybody who wants to see:

```cs
- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
    if (button == nil)
    {
        //no button available to recycle, so create new one
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[menuItems objectAtIndex:index]];
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        //[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }

    //set button label
    //[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //Use these commented lines if you are displaying some text on button
    return button;
}
```